# Triangle incenter relation

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle in which $AB = AC$ and let $I$ be its in-centre. Suppose
$BC = AB + AI$. Find $∠BAC$. I do not see how to start even, please help.
[image]

Comment: Without diagrams these geometry problems are hard both visualizing and solving...

Comment: @DonAntonio I think this a crystal clear problem without any ambiguity. But I will try to add one diagram.

Comment: Oh, perhaps it is, @Sawarnik...I, personally, don't feel like getting into it without seeing diagramatically what I am doing. That's all.

Comment: @DonAntonio oK, making one Geogebra diagram..just wait.

Comment: @DonAntonio Added one :) Maybe now you can look into this.

Comment: You can find AI as the height of the isosceles triangle minus the in radius, and then solve the equation. Slightly ugly but it works (with the answer of 90 degrees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

hint: let $BA=BF \to AI=FI=FC$

Comment: How did you hit upon that idea?

Comment: since $BC=AB+AI$, it is nature to cut a $BF=AB$ to see what will happen. $FC=AI$, we need some connection between two segments.so when you connect all these lines,you will find $FI=AI$.BTW, another approach is add $AI$ to $AB$ which is  Ajay's solution.

Comment: I find your approach more natural and really elegant. 
Often while solving geometry, my one weakness is that I fail to see constructions that could be really helpful, which is the first reason why I failed to solve this. I had immediately set out on using properties and blah blah.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We observe that $\angle AIB = 90^{\circ} + (C/2)$. Extend $CA$ to $D$ such that $AD = AI$. Then, $CD = CB$ by the hypothesis. Hence, $\angle CDB = \angle CBD = 90^{\circ} - (C/2)$.

Thus $\angle AIB + \angle ADB = 180^{\circ}$. Hence $ADBI$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. This implies that $\angle ADI = \angle ABI = B/2$.

But $ADI$ is isosceles, since $AD = AI$. This gives $\angle DAI = 180^{\circ} - 2(\angle ADI) = 180^{\circ} - \angle B$.

Thus $\angle CAI = B$ and this gives $A = 2B$. Since $C = B$, we obtain $4B = 180^{\circ}$ and hence $B = 45^{\circ}$.

Thus we get $A = 2B = 90^{\circ}$.

Sorry can't use latex.

This question is from RMO - 2009: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=78&cid=48&year=2009&sid=48c6849690355f862898aeff37d1965c

Here are some solution other than mine: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1695934&sid=48c6849690355f862898aeff37d1965c#p1695934

Comment: Also join IB I forgot to do that

Comment: Latexed that :)